# SPFx React webpart onAfterPropertyPaneChangesApplied

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx-webparts, react

I have created simple web-part in react and spfx for sharepoint online. In this web-part

weather.tsx have all rendering and function of the web-part. In **componentDidMount** function I call external API function by passing parameter and **setState** which will render web-part with new values.

```
public componentDidMount() {
    this.getWeather(this.props.latitude, this.props.longitude, 'si').then((weatherForcast: IWeather) => {
      this.setState({
        weatherForcast: weatherForcast
      })
    })

    this.getLocation(this.props.latitude, this.props.longitude).then((location: ILocation) => {
      this.setState({
        Locations: location
      })
    })

  }
```

WeatherWebPart.ts have all property pane labels and field with its validation. I make this property pane non-reactive and added **onAfterPropertyPaneChangesApplied** but I don't know how to call those function in this web-part and change the state

**My Repo**

https://github.com/milindsaraswala/weather

I solved my issue by creating componentDidUpdate method with parameter interface of weather and checking old and new value if value mismatch then I will call getWeather and getLocation which will re-render component with new value. I don't know it correct way or not.

Please somebody can guide

Comment: Please help, It will be much appreciate

Comment: **onAfterPropertyPaneChangesApplied** should be invoked automatically whenever a user changes something in the property pane, but I don't think there is enough information here to help, can you post the rest of your component, including how you have set up the property pane?  Perhaps provide a sharing link to a page with this webpart in action?

Comment: I solved my issue by creating **componentDidUpdate** method with parameter interface of weather and checking old and new value if value mismatch then I will call getWeather and getLocation which will re-render component and new value. I don't know it correct way or not. my repo https://github.com/milindsaraswala/weather. Please if you can check

Comment: I get a 404 clicking on the repo link in your comment, you may need to change permissions to allow others to see your repo.

Comment: @willman I make repo public thank you

Comment: Thanks @Milind, I now have access and reviewed your code.  I will note that I did not download or compile, so I cannot guarantee that I didn't miss something somewhere, but it appears you have everything set up correctly. **componentDidUpdate** is the correct place to update your state regardless of whether the property pane is in reactive or non-reactive mode.  In Reactive mode, the componentDidUpdate would be called in "real time" as the user makes changes to values in the property pane, in non-reactive componentDidUpdate only gets called when the user clicks the "Apply" button in the pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue by creating componentDidUpdate method with parameter interface of weather and checking old and new value if value mismatch then I will call getWeather and getLocation which will re-render component with new value.

```
public componentDidUpdate(prevProps: IWeatherProps, prevState: IWeatherStates) {
    let _units = this.props.units ? 'us' : 'si'
    if (this.props.latitude !== prevProps.latitude || this.props.longitude !== prevProps.longitude || this.props.units !== prevProps.units) {
      this.getWeather(this.props.latitude, this.props.longitude, _units).then((weatherForcast: IWeather) => {
        this.setState({
          weatherForcast: weatherForcast
        })
      })

      this.getLocation(this.props.latitude, this.props.longitude).then((location: ILocation) => {
        this.setState({
          Locations: location
        })
      })
    }
  }
```

Hope it can help somebody Thanks @willman for helping